# Chinese government internet censorship - statistics on evasion?

Tags: china, internet, censorship

This may belong better somewhere else but I see this as relevant.

China extensively [censors what its internet users can see.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_China) However, users can circumvent this by using a [VPN](https://www.zdnet.com/article/vpns-can-still-be-used-in-china-despite-march-31-ban/). Are there any statistics gathered (not by the Chinese government of course) that analyze the amount of people in China who bypass this censorship by use of a VPN or other means of evasion?

Comment: The [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) may be a better site for this, they certainly have plenty of questions about [China and VPNs](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=china+vpn) so there may be some statistics on how many people use them.

Comment: If it were possible to easily gather a lot statistics for a given circumvention method, it seems like that method would would be less secure than those methods for which statistics are harder to come by.  The most secure methods probably should have the fewest stats, *per capita* anyway...

Comment: Let me just Google that.  ... Oh...  Heh heh.